# Proxies to the real Tire methods?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I am reading the documentation for the [Tire gem](https://github.com/karmi/tire) and I am a confused about what it mean by the following paragraphs. Could someone explain it?

> In fact, all this time you've been using only proxies to the real Tire
>   methods, which live in the tire class and instance methods of your
>   model. Only when not trampling on someone's foot — which is the
>   majority of cases — will Tire bring its methods to the namespace of
>   your class.
>
> So, instead of writing `Article.search`, you could write
>   `Article.tire.search`, and instead of `@article.update_index` you could
>   write `@article.tire.update_index`, to be on the safe side. Let's have a
>   look on an example with the mapping method:

Answer (score 1):

It means just what it says: Tire tries hard not to drag methods into your model/namespace, and defines its methods only when they don't exist.

As a regular user, you don't have to care about it much. Whenever you call `MyModel.search` or `MyModel.mapping` you can also call `MyModel.tire.search` or `MyModel.tire.mapping`.

Answer (score 0):

to piggy back off what Karmi has said, you might find this useful if for example your Model already has a search defined on it.

So if say, **Post.search** already does something in your rails app, you can just use **Post.tire.search** to do a tire search instead. I like to use it to signal to all developers who might work in the code after I do, that this is a tire method, so they (hopefully) don't spend time wondering where to find a search method in the **Post** model.